# Flask-SocketIO How to allow 2 clients send message to server turn by turn?

Tags: python, html, flask-socketio

I'm building a flask-socketio demo that lets 2 clients send message to server turn by turn. How could I do that? I want when it's client A's turn to send message, client B cannot see the input field in his browser in other to wait for his turn. For example I want to disable the field `input` and `button` in client browser if it's not his turn yet.

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input type="text" id="myMessage">
<button id="sendButton">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by having the server notify the two clients whose turn is it. For example, the server starts by sending a `yourturn` event to A, and a `notyourturn` event to B. As a response to `yourturn` the client shows the intput and submit button, and as a response to `notyourturn` the fields are hidden.

When A emits an event with its data to the server, the server changes the roles of the two clients, and now sends `yourturn` to B and `notyourturn` to A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it :D